# Correct Usage of Classes in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, class, cakephp

Trying to use `$url = Router::url(...);` as per the book ( http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls ) and I can get it to work by adding `use Cake\Routing\Router;` to my controller but I have a feeling that there has to be an easier/better way than that and I recall someone mentioning to never call a function by `Class::function()`.

Through further research (never stop looking) it appears that it's just a Class thing.

1. Load Class with `use Cake\Routing\Router;`
2. Instantiate the Class with `$routes = new Router();`
3. Use the Class instance to call the function `$url = $routes->url(...);`

To use a static(?) function of a Class is it really better to instantiate the Class or just use Router::url()?

Comment: You're pretty late, time to learn namespaces. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php This has nothing to do with CakePHP, it's just namespaces in php. Namespaces are *very* common for some time now. Get used to them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it looks like something simpler than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To use a static(?) function of a Class is it really better to instantiate the Class or just use Router::url()?

url() is a public static method of the class Router. The correct way to call that in PHP is Router::url(...) (using the scope resolution operator, ::).

> I recall someone mentioning to never call a function by Class::function().

If you can find it, I'd be interested to hear his or her reasoning.

If he or she meant that the scope resolution operator is not the best way to access a static method, he or she is mistaken. As far as PHP man is concerned, the scope resolution operator is the correct way to access a public static method from outside the class context: [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Comment: If it works and saves code and there are no big "gotchas" I'm happy. Thanks.

Comment: @CbNrZvWd, very true and great reasons to avoid *writing* static methods. However, OP wanted clarification regarding *calling* a static method.